# PHP if statement inside function

Tags: php

```html
<?php
  function win_bsd(){
    if (strncasecmp(PHP_OS, 'WIN', 3) == 0) {
      echo 'This is a server using Windows!';
    } else {
      echo 'This is a server not using Windows!';
  }
?>
```

Why doesn't this work, it does work if I don't set it as a function. However, when I do set it as a function it give me the error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\shell\shell2.php on line 198

Comment: You need an extra }.

Comment: lots of ways to validate code syntax...use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your closing brackets.

```
<?php
  function win_bsd()
  {
      if (strncasecmp(PHP_OS, 'WIN', 3) == 0) 
      {
          echo 'This is a server using Windows!';
      }
      else 
      {
          echo 'This is a server not using Windows!';
      }
  }
?>
```

Comment: SOLVED.  function win_bsd()
  {
      if (strncasecmp(PHP_OS, 'WIN', 3) == 0) 
      {
          echo 'This is a server using Windows!';
      }
      else 
      {
          echo 'This is a server not using Windows!';
      }
  }

Comment: This solution is given above.

Comment: @yebrah If someone's post was helpful, upvote it. If it provided the correct answer to your issue (like this one did), then also mark it as the accepted answer.